# Generic header placeholder pointers with casting in implementation - a good idea?

Tags: c, casting

I’m building a small multi-platform C library. A design objective is to have a set of header files that are suitably generic, and which define a number of *placeholder pointers* to structs - if that’s the right term - like this:

```c
/* mylib_types.h */

typedef struct _mylib_matrix *mylib_matrix;
```

These placeholders can be used to specify the parameters to the function prototypes in the other headers, like:

```c
/* mylib_api.h */

MY_API mylib_status mylibAddMatrix(mylib_matrix a,
                                   mylib_matrix b, 
                                   mylib_matrix* result);
```

So, that’s fine for the headers - everything is self-contained and stand-alone. Then, when it comes to implementing the library I want to use different underlying, platform specific, libraries to actually implement the methods.

**The idea being that the library is optimised for any given platform, but the API to the library will be universally defined (so easily cross-compiled).**

*The problem I have is that: yes - I have got this working - but in the rather crude way using casting*. I just wonder what the best practice - if any - actually is?

For example, in my implementation of a method I must then remember to immediately cast the placeholder pointer to the actual type of thing we are using for that platforms implementation, and similarly cast back any results.

e.g.

```c
/* mylib_matrix.c */

#include “mylib_types.h"
#include “mylib_api.h”

#include <PlatformSpecificFunkyMatrix.h>

MY_API mylib_status mylibAddMatrix(mylib_matrix a,
                                   mylib_matrix b, 
                                   mylib_matrix* result)
{
    *result = (mylib_matrix)PlatformSpecificFunkyMatrix_AddMatrix(
        (PlatformSpecificFunkyMatrix*)a, 
        (PlatformSpecificFunkyMatrix*)b);

    return MYLIB_SUCCESS;
}
```

This all seems very brittle and liable for me to forget a cast or allowing the compiler to do any type checking. Is it at all principled?

I guess I could be explicit in my types of cast - but that still requires some consideration. Perhaps some pre-processor #defines might help wrap things up, but of course that can get rather messy... I could of course go and redefine the low-level structs (e.g. mylib_matrix) for each implementation, but then we are talking a different set of headers for each platform (again, I could go with the preprocessor to help swap the right definitions in or out).

Hmmm. Maybe I’m dwelling too much upon this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get around the casting.

In the platform specific file, use:

```
struct _mylib_matrix
{
   PlatformSpecificFunkyMatrix* realMatrix;
};
```

and

```
MY_API mylib_status mylibAddMatrix(mylib_matrix a,
                                   mylib_matrix b, 
                                   mylib_matix* result)
{
    PlatformSpecificFunkyMatrix* r = 
       PlatformSpecificFunkyMatrix_AddMatrix(a->realMatrix, b->realMatrix);

    *result = malloc(sizeof(_mylib_matrix));
    *result->realMatrix = r

    return MYLIB_SUCCESS;
}
```

Better still...

You can avoid the double indirection and the need for casting by using:

```
struct _mylib_matrix
{
   // Add all the data here that you have in PlatformSpecificFunkyMatrix
};

typedef struct _mylib_matrix PlatformSpecificFunkyMatrix;
```

and then,

```
MY_API mylib_status mylibAddMatrix(mylib_matrix a,
                                   mylib_matrix b, 
                                   mylib_matix* result)
{
    *result = PlatformSpecificFunkyMatrix_AddMatrix(a, b);    
    return MYLIB_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I like both your suggestions (especially the last one). I will try them out as soon as I can...